# Add a time limit before you can vote on a post

Tags: feature-request, voting, rate-limiting

There needs to be a timer or something on upvoting/downvoting.

I posted an answer to a question and as soon as the page loaded, my answer was already down voted. There is no way someone had the time to read the answer < 10 seconds after it was posted.

Comment: Why? What would the timer solve? And how do you know? If the answer is very short, 10 seconds is enough to read, understand and downvote.

Comment: Sorry, but yes, you can actually read short questions in that time, or read enough to know which way you're going to vote on it.  It usually doesn't take more than a sentence or two to know which way I'll vote on a post.  Also, this isn't a bug, you should learn to tag your questions appropriatly.

Comment: Presumably you mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058352/php-array-operator-fails-with-array-operand-bug/14058414#14058414 and within a few seconds I can see that I do or don't like this answer. It doesn't take much.

Comment: Experienced developers can recognize common mistakes in a fraction of a second. Are you certain your answer is correct?

Comment: There is a timer on selecting an answer why should voting be any different?

Comment: @RyanNaddy: Because it takes more time to write a thoughtful, correct answer than it takes to read a short, incorrect one.

Comment: The downvote was totally justified, as the comment shows

Comment: possible duplicate of [Institute a delay in the ability to down vote new questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157298/institute-a-delay-in-the-ability-to-down-vote-new-questions)

Answer (score 6):

If you're talking about your answer (now deleted) to [in drupal's theme_form_element function, array += operator throws Unsupported operand error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058352/php-array-operator-fails-with-array-operand-bug/14058414#14058414), then it was immediately downvoted for two reasons:

Firstly, the initial line itself is wrong, and it makes the rest of the post meaningless in this case. If you don't know about the operator that the question was talking about, we can reasonably assume that you can't answer questions about it.

> += with an array does not concatenate, that is only for adding numbers like so:

Also, it's rather short. It takes very little time to skim over it and realize that it doesn't have much content.

Comment: I am not complaining or anything because now I know the answer is wrong, all I am saying is that it was down voted so fast that it was like it was added to the database with a down vote by default.

Comment: @RyanNaddy: Yeah. It takes half a second to read the wrong first sentence. Someone saw the post after the realtime update(when you post, everyone viewing the q comes to know of it), read the message, and downvoted. So?